# where to keep symmetric key in the machine?

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-symmetric

As per below statement I have to create a symmetric key to encrypt the data.

Question is, where can I keep the symmetric key in the windows machine where encryption happens?

If user/administrator has access to the key, the he can decrypt the data easily.

> Asymmetric encryption is very processor intensive and, consequently very slow. For that reason, it is not normally used to encrypt large amounts of data.
>
> What is normally done is symmetric encryption is used to encrypt the bulk of the data and asymmetric encryption (public key) is used to encrypt the keys used in the symmetric encryption.
>
> The encrypted keys are transmitted with the encrypted data. The keys are decrypted (private key), then using the symmetric keys the bulk data is decrypted.

Comment: _"If user/administrator has access to the key, the he can decrypt the data easily."_ - yep, that's about it.

Comment: What's the broader context, and what are you looking to achieve? It's often the case that a better, alternative solution exists.

Comment: I am looking for a solution how to protect the symmetric key it, so that it can't be access or tempered?

Comment: You cannot protect anything against an admin. Against a non-admin user, maybe with difficulty, but you would need to run your application under a different user

Comment: The solution to protect the key is that the user never has either the asymmetric or symmetric keys on their machine (at rest or in memory) and is never allowed to encrypt/decrypt the data on their machine. If they have the keys on their machine then they can get access to them.